# Sending data from two factories

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two factories with some data.
These factories are transferred to one controller. In the controller, a function is written when calling these factories to send data to the server.
How is it better to implement it?

I have two ideas:

1. Register in each factory its own method for sending, and from the controller, call them in turn. - I do not like this option, because the methods will be very similar and will differ only in two parameters.
2. Write the send function in the controller and call it twice with different parameters received from the factories. - I do not like this option, it seems to me that it contradicts the Angular's ideas.

I would like to make one, a common (?) For both factories function and call it.
Generally, I would like to learn as correctly to implement such.